# PowerShell script execution within PHP

Tags: php, powershell, iis-7

I am trying to run a powershell script via php.

```
system("C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe -InputFormat none -File AD_Account_Automation.ps1);
```

When I run the php script, it returns the following error in a web browser:

```
File C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Test_Automation.ps1 can not be loaded. The file C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Test_Automation.ps1 is not digitally signed. The script will not execute on the sys tem. Please see "get-help about_signing" for more details.. + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordE xception + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException
```

I have set PowerShell execution policy to both Unrestricted and RemoteSigned, and it doesn't correct the issue. The script runs fine if I call it from the PowerShell command line and if I call it from a command prompt within windows.

I have also tried the following also:

```
exec("C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -File C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\AD_Account_Automation.ps1 < NUL");
```

And IIS just hangs. Any ideas?

Comment: hint: use forward slashes in paths. PHP will auto-translate for you and then you don't have to double them up.

Answer (score 0):

It is almost certain that your hosting environment will not allow this.  ActiveDirectory GroupPolicy overrides digital signing.  WHAM.  Yeah, I know, it sucks, but its for good reasons.  Contact your hosting provider to check if this is the root cause.

Edit: Actually, the root cause is much simpler.  You did not close the string with an end quote ".  That could definitely hang IIS.

Comment: I am the System Admin of all of our Group Policy that we push and we currently do not set this on any of our servers. Also when I run "Get-ExecutionPolicy", it says whatever I last set it to.